# What does the output of the Python extend function mean?

Tags: python

What does the return value (None) for the extend function indicate.

```
common_birds = ["chicken", "blue jay", "crow", "pigeon"]
birds_seen = ["sparrow", "green finch", "gold finch"]

print (common_birds.extend(birds_seen))
# returns None

common_birds.extend(birds_seen)
print (common_birds)
# returns the extended list
```

Comment: It means that the function is not returning anything, since it modifies the list being used to call it

Comment: You probably want to `print(common_birds + birds_seen)`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It means that the method doesn't return something, but works "in place" by extending the list. You're not returning a new list, but changing the old one.

Answer (score 0):

It means that the method does not have a result that you could work with. Instead it has a side effect.

Hopefully the only side effect is the one you'd expect, i.e. that the list is extended.

In your life you'll find `void` methods that have several side effects, some of which are unwanted.